# How to make sure matrix completion can generate a matrix with values in expected range?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra, matrix, recommendation-systems

I am doing a matrix completion project. Assume that I have an incomplete matrix like

```
        func1    func2    func3
prot1     0        0        1
prot2     1        0        1
prot3     0        0        0
```

I want to use Standard Matrix Completion to recover the matrix, like

```
        func1    func2    func3
prot1    0.1      0.9       1
prot2     1       0.2       1
prot3    0.3      0.8      0.7
```

Standard Matrix Completion refers to

$$\min_{W, H} \frac{1}{2} \Vert W \Vert_F^2 + \frac{1}{2} \Vert H \Vert_F^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2} \Vert \Omega \circ (W H^T - Y) \Vert_F^2$$

and $X = WH^T$.

However, I find that the recovered matrix X is not range between 0 and 1, say (just an example, not the truth)

```
        func1    func2    func3
prot1    -0.1     1.1       1
prot2     1       0.2       1
prot3    0.3      2.1      0.7
```

How can I restrict the range (here 0-1) of unobserved entries in X (in particular how can I implement it in Tensorflow)?

Comment: Please fix the formatting in your post using LaTex.

Comment: Add non-negativity constraints.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus How can I add non-negativity constraints in Tensorflow? Besides, how can I restrict the value less than 1?

Comment: Your "incomplete" matrix looks quite complete to me.

Comment: What do W, H and T represent? What is their shape? What are their properties?

Comment: Questions about Tensorflow are off-topic here. This is not a programming site. We can help you with algorithms, not software libraries.

Comment: X-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3188131/339790